# Show Elapsed time on Java Frame title bar

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I am trying to make it show elapsed time on frame.setTitle in live time , but i am having difficulties finding what to do, can someone plesae help me? this is my code

```java
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss:aa yyyy/MM/dd");
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
                    

frame.setTitle("[SESSION] - "+ myUsername +" Elapsed Time " + dateFormat.format(cal.getTime()) );
```

Comment: Is the problem here in the setting of the title bar, or working out how to execute the code that does the job? Or something completely different? You say you're having difficulties, but what exactly are the difficulties?

Comment: i just dont know how to add a refresh on the frame, im gussing it needs a @overthrow and run {}

Comment: Use a Swing `Timer` to call an `ActionListener` which has the code snippet seen above as the code in the `actionPerformed` method. For further details see [How to Use Swing Timers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html).

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could create a Timer that executes every second to update the title (I'm not sure how it would be performance-wise but it should do the job)

```
    class UpdateFrame extends TimerTask {
        public void run() {
            frame.setTitle("[SESSION] - "+ myUsername +" Elapsed Time " + dateFormat.format(cal.getTime()) );
        }
    }

    // And From your main() method or any other method, maybe where you initialize the JFrame
    NoiseMap noisemap;
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule(new UpdateFrame(), 0, 1000);
```

you also need to pass the JFrame object and probably the DateFormat or Calendar from when you begin the count, I haven't tested it but it should work

```
    class UpdateFrame extends TimerTask {
        JFrame frame;
        public UpdateFrame(JFrame frame) {
            this.frame = frame;
        }

        public void run() {
            frame.setTitle("[SESSION] - "+ myUsername +" Elapsed Time " + dateFormat.format(cal.getTime()) );
        }
    }

    // And From your main() method or any other method, maybe where you initialize the JFrame
    NoiseMap noisemap;
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule(new UpdateFrame(frame), 0, 1000);
```

Comment: Swing components should be updated on the EDT. Using a Swing `Timer` / `ActionListener` combination ensures that happens.